# Difference between program counter in the executable and program counter in the main memory

Tags: computer-science, cpu-architecture

what is the difference between the program counter in the executables and the program counter in the main memory?

My professor gave an example about the program counter in executables and their values in decimals, he wrote that the PC increments by 4 for each instruction.

Like this:

0000

0004

0008

what about the program counter in main memory then? What do their values in decimal look like? Are they as same as the values above?

Thank you!

Comment: Hmm - usually there is only one program counter per thread, and - unless that thread is suspended - it lives in a CPU register.

Comment: I am in the computer architecture class, we were talking about MIPS architecture. I just want to know the difference between **program counter in executable** and **program counter in main memory**.

Comment: I don't understand your questions. They is only one program counter associated with each thread of the program.

Comment: @Rishit, my professor had a question about this... So, I guess they should all be the same since there is no difference between PC in executables and PC in Main Memory?

Comment: @David Yes the are same. I guess what professor might be discussing about is address space. In executable, PC has a virtual address, while in main memory it has physical address. Otherwise there is no difference.

Comment: @Rishit I see, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such thing as a "program counter in main memory". You might be referring to physical and virtual memory addressing.

When you write and compile a program, you do so as if you have the whole memory space for yourself. you do not care about other programs working on the same system, and you do not worry about writing to some other program's memory space or some other program writing to your memory space. How is that?

This is called [virtual memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory). Each program has its own **virtual** memory space. all addresses inside a program whether they are instruction addresses (like in program counter) or data addresses are inside this virtual memory space. On the other hand, your system has an actual **physical** memory space which all programs will reside in. Translation between these spaces are done by the operating system (and perhaps some support from the processor itself, depending on the architecture. x86 processors use a structure called **TLB** to support virtual to physical address translation).

Your program has a program counter which is in the virtual address space of the program but in main memory it is addressed using the physical address space.